# For loop over a list for pairwise distance implementation in Mathematica

Tags: list-manipulation

I am new to *Mathematica* and want to implement the following functionality in *Mathematica*. Suppose I have the following list

```
data4 = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {1, 3}};
```

I want to calculate the `Euclidean distance` between consecutive elements and also maintain a value for the total of euclidean distances.A rough pseudocode in java would look like:

```
 for(i=0; i<data4.length; i++)
 {
  distance_array = data[i+1] - data[i];
  total = total+distance;
 }
```

I tried this in *Mathematica*.but it failed.

```
 knot2 = Table[EuclideanDistance[i, i + 1], {i, data4}];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
Table[EuclideanDistance[i, i + 1], {i, data4}];
```

fails because for every step, `i` is a two-element list, like `{1,2}`.  So `i+1` is just `{1,2}+1` or `{2,3}`.  This works,

```
Table[EuclideanDistance[data4[[i]], data4[[i + 1]]], {i, Length@data4 - 1}]
```

This also works, and is a bit shorter,

```
Norm /@ (Rest@(data4 - RotateRight[data4]))
(* {Sqrt[2], 1} *)
```

[`Accumulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Accumulate.html) gives a running total, and [`Total`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Total.html) gives the total distance,

```
Accumulate[Norm /@ (Rest@(data4 - RotateRight[data4]))]
Total[Norm /@ (Rest@(data4 - RotateRight[data4]))]
(* {Sqrt[2], 1 + Sqrt[2]} *)
(* 1 + Sqrt[2] *)
```

### Edit

I think this is what you are trying to do, you have your data

```
data4 = RandomInteger[20, {5, 2}]
(* {{19, 17}, {8, 7}, {1, 14}, {16, 16}, {2, 13}} *)
```

you have your distances,

```
distances = Table[EuclideanDistance[data4[[i]], data4[[i + 1]]], {i, Length@data4 - 1}]
(* {Sqrt[221], 7 Sqrt[2], Sqrt[229], Sqrt[205]} *)
```

And this is your normalized running total,

```
Accumulate[distances]/Total[distances]

(* {Sqrt[221]/(7 Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[205] + Sqrt[221] + Sqrt[229]), (
 7 Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[221])/(
 7 Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[205] + Sqrt[221] + Sqrt[229]), (
 7 Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[221] + Sqrt[229])/(
 7 Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[205] + Sqrt[221] + Sqrt[229]), 1} *)
```

Comment: Hi jason, but how to maintain a variable and add all the distances...do we need to loop over again?

Comment: @kranthikumar - I guess I was unclear about what you mean there.  If you just want the total of the distances, `Total@Table[EuclideanDistance[data4[[i]], data4[[i + 1]]], {i, 
   Length@data4 - 1}]` will work.

Comment: Thank you !! I am trying to generate t0,t1,t2....tn as knots to pass them as a parameter to a function I developed. It should take the list we generated just now and calculate its values such that they are between 0,1 as below.

t0=0
t1=|D1-D0|/Total
t2 = (|D1-D0|+|D2-D0|)/Total
......tn
knot1 = Table[t, {t, 0.0, 1.0, 1/m}];

more info if you want what i am trying to do is in link below
http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/INT-APP/PARA-chord-length.html

Can you help on this too please....

Comment: @kranthikumar, in your expression in that comment, is `Total`, the running total (as in the total so far) or the total distance of the whole list?

Comment: its the Total distance of all the pairwise distances we calculated

Comment: pairwisedistances = Norm /@ (Rest@(data4 - RotateRight[data4]))

knot1 = Table[t, {t, 0.0, 1.0, 1/m}];
knot2 = Table[
   t, {t, 0.0, 1.0, Accumulate[distances]/Total[distances]}];
Print ["Printing knot2", knot2];
Print [uniform[5, knot1, data]];

This gives error "The first Norm argument should be a number, vector, or matrix"

Comment: @kranthikumar, do you get the same error if you replace `Norm /@ (Rest@(data4 - RotateRight[data4]))` with `Table[EuclideanDistance[data4[[i]], data4[[i + 1]]], {i, 
  Length@data4 - 1}]` ?

Comment: data2 = Table[{t, Sqrt[t] + 0.4 RandomReal[]}, {t, 0.0, 10.0, 10/m}];
data = data2;

pairwisedistances = 
  Table[EuclideanDistance[data[[i]], data[[i + 1]]], {i, 
    Length@data - 1}];

knot1 = Table[t, {t, 0.0, 1.0, 1/m}];
knot2 = Table[
   t, {t, 0.0, 1.0, 
    Accumulate[pairwisedistances]/Total[pairwisedistances]}];
Print ["Printing knot2", knot2];
Print [uniform[5, knot1, data]];

The Error Now is "Table::iterb: "Iterator <<1>> does not have appropriate bounds.""

Comment: `m` is not defined

Comment: m is 30, the number of points and defined

Comment: Also, I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish with the line `Table[t, {t, 0.0, 1.0, 
  Accumulate[pairwisedistances]/Total[pairwisedistances]}]`.  If I read correctly, `Accumulate[pairwisedistances]/Total[pairwisedistances]` **is** the knot list that you are looking for.

Comment: I am trying to print values starting with 0.0 and ending with 1...these are my knots

Comment: Then you just need `Prepend[Accumulate[pairwisedistances]/Total[pairwisedistances], 0]`

Comment: Yes ...you are right..!! I finished my task...all thanks to you :D....Thank you for  being patient.....I am new to Mathematica and it looks like there is a hell lot of stuff to learn... Cheers !!

Answer (score 2):

like this?

```
data4 = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {1, 3}};
Norm /@ Differences[data4]
```

> ```
> {Sqrt[2], 1}
> ```

total of `Euclidean distances`

```
Total[Norm /@ Differences[data4]]
```

> ```
> 1 + Sqrt[2]
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Just some variants:

```
{##, Total@##} &@(EuclideanDistance @@@ Partition[data4, 2, 1])
{##, Total@##} &@(Sqrt[#.#] & /@ Differences[data4])
```

both yield: {{Sqrt[2], 1}, 1 + Sqrt[2]}

Answer (score 1):

```
f = Developer`PartitionMap[Sqrt[Plus @@ ((Subtract @@ #)^2)] &, #, 2, 1 ] &;
(* or f = Developer`PartitionMap[EuclideanDistance @@ # &, #, 2, 1 ] &; *)
f@{{19, 17}, {8, 7}, {1, 14}, {16, 16}}
```

> {Sqrt[221], 7 Sqrt[2], Sqrt[229]}

```
Accumulate@%
```

> {Sqrt[221], 7 Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[221], 7 Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[221] + Sqrt[229]}